# Always better to wait?

Tags: programming-practices, development-process, theory

I've been wondering if this concept has a name and a consolidated theory behind.

> If you need to build software, but you don't need it right now,
>   it's always better to wait because the technology will be better in
>   the future.

I'm pretty sure it is true:

- IT tech is getting better over time: better softwares, better libraries, better IDE, ...
- So any development is going to be cheaper (not taking into account other factors like market state, ...)
- And any resulting product is going to be better in terms of speed, robustness, look and feel, ...

But I can't find any theory or name for this concept. Can you point me into the right direction?

### EDIT

I wanted to clarify some things, as all answers, although interesting, are slightly off topic:

- I know I will need this software at some point in the future, as its functionalities covers some critical parts of my business. It's for internal use, and it will replace an existing one that is relying on obsolete tech and that users don't like.
- There is no concurrence
- I'm not talking about cutting-edge tech. It's plain normal development. The assumption is that this normal dev will get better and easier as time passes. Neither now or in the future do I plan on using tech that would qualify me as an "early adopter".

  - In other words, the idea is to take advantage of the fact that what will be mainstream in a few years will be better than what is mainstream now.

Comment: In the business world, it is often framed as the "First Mover versus Fast Follower" debate. https://hbr.org/2012/06/first-mover-or-fast-follower It is hereby assuming that you are not merely referring to the act of procrastination or some school of nihilism.

Comment: Did you notice a conflict in the statement? _If you **need** to build software, but you **don't need** it right now,_ - "need" vs "don't need"

Comment: @Fabio I read the question and immediately thought of [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)

Comment: A better reason to not build software that you don't need is that your ability to modify code will always exceed your ability to predict the future. Future proofing software does not mean writing code you think you will need: it means making your code ready for change.

Comment: @Fabio I need to make a website for my business. But I don't need to make it right now until my business is actually ready to start.

Comment: @Fabio, The cas I'm thinking of is in fact "I know I will need a replacement for this software, because it relies on obsolete tech and users don't like it", but it could hold for a few more years probably.

Answer (score 6):

On terminology, I think you're looking for the "early adopter penalty" or the "penalty of taking the lead". It's a concept that has been recognised for at least 100 years.

As to whether your assertions about software are true, that's another question entirely. There is also a concept of a "laggard penalty", where organisations adopt a technology too late.

Comment: I see what you mean, however I think it might not apply here. I clarified the question to say that I'm not talking about cutting edge technology, only plain normal application development. My assumption is that this dev will get easier and better as time passes. Neither now nor in the future do I plan on using tech that would qualify me as an "early adopter". I just think that what will be mainstream in a few years will be better than what is mainstream now.

Comment: @Legisey, the same basic principle applies. I doubt software development will get significantly easier in the near term however. Once you factor in increased demands and expectations, it may well become more difficult in future even notwithstanding underlying improvements in technology.

Comment: @Legisey: "early" and "late" are subjective. What you call "normal/late adoption", someone else could call "early/normal adoption", and so on. The point is not to objectively label these things, but to compare them (earlier, later).

Answer (score 4):

The principle you are referring to is to **postpone architectural decisions** for as long as possible. Not so much because there will be better options later but because you will be able to make a more informed decision later. Which is important because architectural decisions are by definition the most expensive ones if you get them wrong.

Too often a company buys some technology for a lot of money after which that becomes an argument to use it for all sorts of applications, whether it is a good fit or not. This must then go on until there will be return on investment (which can take a while because it was not a great way to start).

I do not have a catchy name for this kind of stupidity. Business as usual perhaps?

[Edit]

I am aware I just answered a slightly different question than the one you were asking. I did so because it is more relevant to our field (software engineering). But it just occurred to me there is a perfect Dutch expression for the phenomena you are bringing to the table:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_handicap_of_a_head_start

And apparently someone took the trouble of translating it. As a Dutchman I am not quite satisfied with this translation though. I would rather call it "the law of the braking lead" which is a pretty literal translation that puts more emphasis on the fact you are ahead of the pack and not so much on that you started earlier. The point is you will have to deal with legacy where those that joined the party later do not (or at least will not have to deal with your kind of legacy). This gives them a chance to overtake you.

Answer (score 3):

> If you need to build software, but you don't need it right now, it's always better to wait because the technology will be better in the future.

If this were true we would never move forward. Rather then put a name to this theory I’m going to point you to a better one.

Value features, not code.

Code is what ties you to the past. Never let code hold an opinion over what you should do. Throw away old code the moment you see the better way.

Hold to this and investigating new ideas is much less expensive because your under no obligation to maintain it.

So long as the core features are maintained, prospective features can come and go as you decide what direction to go in.

Work like that and you can solve needs people didn’t even know they had.

Yes, technology will be better in the future. But technology has to start somewhere. Play around and find out what works.

Comment: Valuing features and not code is surely like valuing the grin but not the cat?

Comment: @steve Value the cat, when what you need is the grin, and you end up stuck with humorless cats. "I've often seen a cat without a grin"

Comment: But the punchline is that she's "never seen a grin without a cat!". Code is not a frippery at the periphery of a feature - it is at the very least a detailed description of the essence of the feature, and often it also incorporates a very careful integration and settlement with the technical features and limitations of the host environment.

Answer (score 2):

This is a neat Software Economics question.
The cost to develop the software is (sort of) fixed.  (engineering salaries, outside the US bubble are just keeping pace with inflation.)
Loosely speaking, your MVP will have a fixed scope. This doesn't change, you hope, over time, ( beware competitors)

You can say that that cost is M. (The absolute value doesn't matter.)

Where M = Cost of hardware + Cost of software (X) + Cost to duplicate software

Cost to duplicate software is generally zero, or nearly so.

Unlike most of the economy, the price of the system to run the software on (generally speaking) trends downwards roughly at roughly -7%. circa 2020 (check wikipedia, moores law)

So we have Deflation in system costs.

Your cost of software per customer is X,
where X = cost to develop / number of customers.

Now, as your number of customers goes to more than, say a million, X trends towards zero.

Now under deflationary pressure, there is a strong incentive to postpone investment, as it will be cheaper, later. (check wikipedia, deflation)

So if you're aiming for a million customers, 
M(next year) = M *0.93.

Now, some parts of your MVP might be difficult to implement today, for example, if you needed 2ms latency on screen updates, that quite fast. You may have to resort to expensive techniques to and hardware get that performance.

Now, we wait 5 years.

The 2ms latency requirement has been eaten away at by Moores law and friends.
The total cost of the hardware required is now about 70% of what it was.

M(5) ~= 0.70 M

Now, the system development cost will probably scale down faster then the 7% scale factor, becauase you can get away with easier techniques. Try running an electron app on a 10 year old computer, for example.
There's also another positive feedback loop, where all the things your software  (and it's development tools) depend on get cheaper at 7% too. So that 70% is in fact, a lot less. Measureing this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Now, if you were, perhaps selling software to run on someones phone,or PC the Customer is Paying for the hardware themselves.

So now your pool of customers gets bigger every year, as more phones can now run your app.

So yes, it makes economic sense to wait, sometimes.

Sadly, if you already HAVE a product, the same thing happens anyway. The cost to replicate your product drops annually also.**

Anecdote time: I watched a senior engineer's startup,they'd spent two years optimising some 3D graphics rendering for landscapes in 1999. By 2005, the DirectX demos on modern hardware out-performed his solution, on 1999 hardware. About a normal engineer-year of work, all that IP, whihc now had a market value of zero.

Notes: Moores law and friends have flattened off a bit lately, with  our current 7% comparing terribly to the 25% we used to have. Maybe its time to write software.

** If your product has a lot of functions, the MVP for a competitor, is... all of your useful functions. The classic blunder used to be to try to write a word processor to compete with MS Word. Just reading the file formats for inter-operation would be prohibitively expensive. Open source software and libraries can make put zeroes in interesting places in the cost analysis of software.

Comment: Most of the times the market will render your calculations meaningless. Being first to market is still a determining factor for success in this industry.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not planning on selling the software though. It's for internal use.

Comment: Also, I would be more interested by the evolution of the cost of the software itself than by the cost of the system/hardware to run it.

Comment: @Legisey, I would think in most cases, the cost of having no software at all in the interim, far exceeds any change in the cost of producing software over timeframes as small as say a decade. And even over timescales like 40 years, it's not apparent that software costs have reduced.

Comment: @Martin  Is it a good time to have a company making self-driving trucks? No. you need to wait for the hardware to get cheaper to get  product at price the market will accept. First to market should mean that we all use Xerox Alto's. But we don't.

Comment: @Steve Have software costs dropped since 1980? I'm using a computer running an operating system that cost zero dollars, with an IDE that cost zero, and a compiler that cost zero too. Now, I remember buying software in early 1980's.. and I paid money. Costs have changed.

Comment: @Tim So, you suggest people should wait bringing their software product to market until the cost of hardware and software tools dropped some more? (like, till they become negative?) All the cost is in development and that cost has been pretty constant over the years. It's functionality what client pay for.

Comment: @TimWilliscroft, so if you were running a business, and you'd waited from 1980 until now to get a computer system, how much increased profit do you think you'd have taken overall?

Comment: @Steve Straw man. However, If I'd taken the money to start a business and dropped it in the share market, I'd be pretty happy in 2019 (2020, maybe not). "Opportunity Cost" is an important idea from economics. OP's company has an existing legacy system and hardware as he's clarified, so this question is a classic X-Y question posting. In OP's case, waiting will probably save money, as they users only dislike it, it's still working. Replacing legacy systems gets easier over time, and they can probably virtualize it and ditch the legacy hardware too.

Answer (score 2):

@Steve is correct that this is the "early adopter penalty". But I wanted to address the underlying assertion, which is the literal title of your question:

> **Always** better to wait?

**No**.

Your assertion to wait is based on technology improving over time, but with user expectations remaining fixed. That last part is the flaw in your reasoning.

The proof is in the pudding: if technology always advanced faster than expectations, then all software development would shorten as time goes on, and we would require less software developers (per project) than we did 10 years ago. Clearly, that's not the case.

It's true that web technology has massively improved over the last decades and it's easier now to build a complex website than it was back then. However, so too have user expectations shifted. Today, you can bang out a 90's style website in no time, but you cannot get away with a 90's-style website in today's market if you want your users to *like* your website.

User expectations lag slightly behind technological advancements (as it takes some time for a new technology to become commonplace), but they advance at the same rate. Think of it like two cars driving at the same speed, but one is slightly behind the other. No matter how long you wait, the cars will always have the same distance, and thus the effort required for one to meet the other will be the same.

---

So you'd think that it's then a zero sum game, where expectations and technological advancement cancel each other out. **That is mostly correct**.

But there are also cases where increased expectations lead to a [superlinear](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superlinear) increase in the technology required to meet expectations. Video games are a great example here.

As graphical quality has improved over time, a video game's total development time dedicates increasingly larger portions to visuals and graphical fidelity.

Going back to the past, graphics were less than 50% of the development time. Take Pong as an extreme example here.

Compare this to if you were to release Pong today as a new game with similar high market appeal, and consider the amount of graphics you'd need to entice customers. Even if you assume that the game mechanics don't need to be expanded, the visuals will take much more time than they did for original Pong.

This is just a simple example using extremes, but if you delve into modern game development, you'll see the same pattern emerge everywhere. Development teams have heavily shifted towards increasing graphics-related roles, more so than gameplay roles.

This means that if you want to develop a game and have limited means, you're better off building your game today instead of one year from now, as the bar you have to reach (to get consumers interested in your game) is lower now than it will be one year from now.